# Android app to monitor sound decibel levels for an entire day and output to data or graph

Tags: android, audio, monitoring

Requirements

- Android app
- Measures sound levels, sampling continuously or once every X seconds
- Can measure over long periods of time (8 hours)
- Can graph the results or output the data (time + measurement)

Ideal use case:

- start app
- click "start monitoring"
- display shows current decibel level and a graph of the entire current measurement session
- "stop" button stops measurement but stores record
- clicking stopped recording sessions shows their start time, duration, graph, and option to output data (save as text file, send over email)

Comment: The ERP software OpenBravo has plans for e-commerce integration but unfortunately it seems to be still in designe phase: http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects:Ecommerce_Integration

Comment: Many sensor apps have sound dB monitoring. I know Sensor Sense has a graph and csv export, but I'm not sure how it'd do on long-term monitoring.